# PHP MySQL &amp; vs & issue

Tags: php, html

In database table, column `name` is `varchar(255)`

encoding on column: `utf8_unicode_ci`

Example value in column: `Garner Heating &amp; Cooling`

When I query for this value, using:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM bizs WHERE name = 'Garner Heating &amp; Cooling'";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

     if ($conn->affected_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "OLD Name: " . $row['name'] . "\n";
        }
     }

}
```

OUTPUT:
`OLD Name: Garner Heating & Cooling`

**Why is the `&amp;` being converted to `&`?**

Comment: You are viewing it in a browser. Entities display as the character they are encoding in browsers, double encode if you require the entity. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php Ideally your DB would have `&` and your encoding would be done only for outputting.

Comment: Thank you for this ... was trying to update values in Table to decoded entities, so $name = htmlspecialchars_decode($row'name'); does the trick, and will double encode to see that in the browser!

Comment: It's called XSS. You should look up how to prevent it.

Comment: XSS doesn't apply in this "one-time use" sanitization script (by myself), for data properly escaped before db UPDATE, with no user input, on a server that doesn't face the public internet.  Marking this question as a duplicate is incorrect because anyone encountering this issue won't be searching for "XSS" on google.  They will be searching for similar to my title.  Cool story tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line to see encoded data same:

```
echo "OLD Name: " . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use htmlentities function :

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM bizs WHERE name = 'Garner Heating &amp; Cooling'";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

     if ($conn->affected_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "OLD Name: " . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
        }
     }

}
```